# Create contact in Sendinblue with attribute not run from python

Tags: python, api, sendinblue

When I create within the attribute this run.

```
payload = f'{{"email":"{email}","updateEnabled":true}}'
```

But when I try to agree the attributes not run. I had try with:

```
payload = f'{{email":"{email}","attributes": {"codigo": "0612345678"},"updateEnabled":true}}'
payload = f'{{"email": "thomas.bianchi@email.com","attributes": {"codigo": "0612345678"}}}'
payload = f'{{email":"{email}","codigo":"fkfkfkkffk","updateEnabled":false}}'
payload = f'{{email":"{email}","codigo":"{codigo}"}}'
```

view.py

```
from __future__ import print_function
import time
import sib_api_v3_sdk
from sib_api_v3_sdk.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint
import requests

payload = f'{{"email":"{email}","updateEnabled":true}}'
headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'content-type': "application/json",
    'api-key': "keys-ANON"
    }
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why are you using the `request` for making the call. You can directly call the methods provided by the python wrapper itself for creating the contact. I got a sample code running:

```
    from __future__ import print_function
import time
import sib_api_v3_sdk
from sib_api_v3_sdk.rest import ApiException
from pprint import pprint

configuration = sib_api_v3_sdk.Configuration()
configuration.api_key['api-key'] = 'API-KEY'
api_instance = sib_api_v3_sdk.ContactsApi(sib_api_v3_sdk.ApiClient(configuration))
attr = {"SMS": "919123456789"} #Valid phone number along with country code
create_contact = sib_api_v3_sdk.CreateContact(email="email@example.com", attributes=attr, update_enabled=True)

try:
    api_response = api_instance.create_contact(create_contact)
    pprint(api_response) #Id of the newly created contact will be returned
except ApiException as e:
    print("Exception occurred: %s\n" % e)
```

One thing to make sure while updating the attributes is that the **same** attribute must be present in your list of attributes before trying to set or update its value otherwise it will be ignored.

There is an official detailed [documentation](https://github.com/sendinblue/APIv3-python-library/blob/master/docs/ContactsApi.md#example-2) on the Python wrapper provided by SIB.